# What is Mathematica?

Tags: discussion

I thought it is a site for **mathematics**, but just now came through [another site](https://math.stackexchange.com/). What is the difference by the way? I am new here.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a Mathematical software system.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: This is a rare glimpse, my friends. At least one person actually bothered to ask (but sadly did not look around enough) instead of proceeding blindly to ask a question not very related to the software we're using. Why, indeed, do people not see the difference between this and math.SE at once?

Comment: @J.M. There was a discussion a long time ago about the site name. I remember me myself saying that too many people will be asking math question here ... anyway.

Comment: I find StackExchange very strict, much professional. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image: Mathematics SE]

Help and support with **mathematics** (as a field of science) you can find at [**Mathematics Stack Exchange**](https://math.stackexchange.com/). It is a question and answer site for people **studying math** at any level and professionals in related fields.

---

[image: Mathematica SE]

Help and support with ***Mathematica*** (a computer algebra system) you can find here, at [**Mathematica® Stack Exchange**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). It is a question and answer site for **users of Wolfram *Mathematica* and the Wolfram Language**. *Mathematica* is a computational software program, developed by [Wolfram Research](http://www.wolfram.com/), used in many scientific, engineering, mathematical and computing fields, based on symbolic mathematics. The [Wolfram Language](http://www.wolfram.com/language/?source=nav) is the programming language used in *Mathematica*.

---

The difference is how you use your ware;

- On [Maths.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) you are using pen, paper and brainware.
- On [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) you are using pen, paper, brainware, hardware and the software *Mathematica*.

Comment: Made the difference even more obvious, for newcomers.